# Not able to set text property of asp:label

Tags: c#, master-pages

Ok, I thought I knew how to do this.... even though it has been one year since I last programmet .Net.

**Update:**
I've moved my code from the MasterPage to an aspx Template. And still nothing is displayed.

In my aspx templatefile I have the following code:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="mainAndRightRegion" runat="server">
       My label: <asp:Label ID="txtString" CssClass="myTestLabel" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

In my code behind, I have the following code:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  this.txtString.Text = "TEST";
}
```

What am I mssing here?

Comment: Is that code behind on your master page or the normal page?

Comment: It's the code behind on my masterpage. The solution is set to retrieve a dynamic property t osett the css style. But it's not working. So I wanted to se what the dynamic property outputs. Therefore I added the Lable and wanted to output the dynamic property which is a string.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Does it not compile, do you get a runtime error, or does no text appear in the label?

Comment: I get no output. I should get the text "TEST"

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that postback / viewstate handling in the child-page is blowing out the values you have set in the master page.

Try moving the second block of code, where you are setting `testLabel.Text = "Test"` to the prerender event handler.

Comment: Load event should be safe for this, unless something else is over-writing it later.

Comment: Should be safe... but this is in the MASTER page, which triggers the Load event before the Page's Load event.

Comment: yeah, that's what I though.
I will try this and see what happends.

Comment: Ok, now I've moved it into an aspx template file, but it still doesn't work. Weird. Any suggestions?